# Updating newly added field in CRM 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have added few fields into crm entity.
Its fine whenever I save/update a record from the CRM form.
However updating or saving the record using the web service does not populating the newly added fields.

Any thoughts? My code goes something like this:

```cs
CrmService service = GetCrmService();
salesorder so = new salesorder();
so.newfield =CrmTypes.CreateCrmMoney(somevalue);
..
..
..
service.Create(so);
```

The rest of the fields get updated/saved.But the 'newfield' is not getting any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.Turned out the crm web service needs to be updated after new attributes has been published.

P/S: Appreciate the response.

Comment: But if you have intellisense you have the updates of webservice. Mark your reply as answer.

Comment: Yes, my local intellisense on my dev machine reflected the updates of the web service. But the same web service was not updated where it was hosted. Hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You have a valid value in somevalue? You can try put something like that:

```cs
CrmTypes.CreateCrmMoney((decimal)5.00);
```

Be careful with the configuration of this field, precision and max\min value.

Another thing you can check is the trace, if it's launch any exception.

Comment: I don't mean a exception in code! The infrastructure of CRM don't launch exceptions, when a error occurred is write in [trace](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490).